# How to split a string after a dot in java

Tags: java

I have a requirement that i have to split a String that have .xls or .xlsx extention. I have to upload the file from local and save it in a directory in my project.i am able to do it. Now the requirement is that i have to check if that file which is uploaded if duplicate i will change the name of the file and that append the extention to that.So that i multiple client access  the file  and try to upload each file with a different name should save into the  folder.So i am doing this to split the Sring but i dont want this approach.

```
public class RenameFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = new String("Udemy.txt");

        String result[] = str.split("\\.");

        for (String ff : result) {
            System.out.println(ff);
        }
    }
}
```

i dont a  loop for manipulating my String.i want something that will just cut the fileName and ext and i can store it somewhere and then after opeartion i also can append them.plese help ..

Comment: You should never do new String("some string");

Comment: So first you ask how to split a String and then you say you don't want that approach? Then what do you exactly want? Also after split with ("."), `result[0]` should stores your file name and `result[1]` will stores your extension.

Comment: you can try append timestamp in your file name so each file will be saved with different name...(this will have to consider other test cases as well when using this)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The file extension is the part *after the last dot* and therefore the following should work

```
String str = "Udemy.txt";
String fileName = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("."));
String extension = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use like that,

```
 String result[] = str.split(".");
String fileName = result[0];
String extension = result[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
String fileName = "MyFile.xls";     
int dotIndex = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
String name = fileName.substring(0, dotIndex); // MyFile
String extension = fileName.substring(dotIndex); // .xls
// then you can change and re-construct the file name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "Udemy.txt";
int ix = str.lastIndexOf('.');
if (ix >= 0) {
    String ext = str.substring(ix);
    String root = str.substring(0, ix);
    ...
}
```